# Merge two sorted linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to merge two sorted linked lists. Here I'm just trying to implement my own algorithm. Of course there are many solutions given on internet. The code is :

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    int countA = 0, countB = 0;
    while(headA){countA++; headA = headA->next;}
    while(headB){countB++; headB = headB->next;}
    Node *res, *tres;
    res = new Node();
    res->next = NULL;
    tres = res;
    for(int i = 0; i < countA+countB-1; i++)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        temp->next = NULL;
        tres->next = temp;
        tres = tres->next;
    }
    while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)
    {
        if(headA->data > headB->data)
        {
            res->data = headB->data;
            res = res->next;
            headB = headB->next;
        }
        else if(headA->data < headB->data)
        {
            res->data = headA->data;
            res = res->next;
            headA = headA->next;
        }
    }
    while(headA)
    {
        res = headA;
    }
    while(headB)
    {
        res = headB;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is just a function which returns the head address of merged linked list.

Consider this input / output example :

```
Input (stdin):

3
4
1 3 5 6
3
2 4 7
1
15
1
12
0
2
1 2

My Output (stdout)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0
0 0

Expected Output
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
12 15
1 2
```

So, my output prints all zero. This is due to the problem in this segment of code :

```
Node *res, *tres;
    res = new Node();
    res->next = NULL;
    tres = res;
    for(int i = 0; i < countA+countB-1; i++)// this is creating a new linked list.
    {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        temp->next = NULL;
        tres->next = temp;
        tres = tres->next;
    }
```

I think the linkage between the tres and res is not properly happening. Can you please tell me how to correct this problem.

Update :

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{

    int countA = 0, countB = 0;
    Node* tempA, *tempB;
    tempA = headA; tempB = headB;
    while(headA){countA++; tempA = tempA->next;}
    while(headB){countB++; tempB = tempB->next;}
    Node *res, *tres;
    res = new Node();
    res->next = NULL;
    tres = res;
    for(int i = 0; i < countA+countB-1; i++)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node();
        temp->next = NULL;
        tres->next = temp;
        tres = tres->next;
    }
    while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)
    {
        if(headA->data > headB->data)
        {
            res->data = headB->data;
            res = res->next;
            headB = headB->next;
        }
        else if(headA->data < headB->data)
        {
            res->data = headA->data;
            res = res->next;
            headA = headA->next;
        }
    }
    if(headA)
    {
        res= headA;
        //res = res->next;
        //headA = headA->next;
    }
    if(headB)
    {
        res = headB;
        //res = res->next;
        //headB = headB->next;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This time `~ no response on stdout ~`

Comment: NULL is obsolete for c++

Comment: Why do you need to count elements in those lists before merging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with this part of the code.

```
while(headA){countA++; headA = headA->next;}
while(headB){countB++; headB = headB->next;}
```

After this loop is executed, both headA & headB are pointing to NULL;
So when

```
while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)
```

loop starts, it doesn't even enter the loop. Since this loop is responsible for assigning values and it doesn't enter this loop. Hence all your values are set to default 0.

As @Slava mentioned you don't even need this loop. As your directly iterating over Nodes and can stop when NULL occurs.

**Create a temp pointer and use that pointer to calculate countA and countB.**

Something like

```
Node* temp;
temp = headA;
while(temp){countA++; temp = temp->next;}
temp = headB;
while(temp){countB++; temp = temp->next;}
```

Also, this may result in infinite loop. Please increment the Node inside the loop. or just change the condition to an if, instead of while.

```
    while(headA)
    {
        res = headA;
    }
    while(headB)
    {
        res = headB;
    }
```

**Update -**

Another Issue:
Your returning res after this computation, which is pointing to the last element. Hence the output would be just one digit.

What you can do is

```
tres = res;
for(int i = 0; i < countA+countB-1; i++)
{
    ...
}
tres = res; // Add this line, so your keeping track of the original head
while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)
```

And finally `return tres;` instead of return res; With this you'll be returning the original head.

Comment: "Create a temp pointer and use that pointer to calculate countA and countB." he does not need to count at all.

Comment: @Slava True. But since he mentioned he wants it working with the implementation that he provided, I wasn't planning on removing any of the changes. I'll add a note about this as well.

Comment: I'm using countA and countB for creating a new linked list which is res.

Comment: implement all the thing you told me, does not give any output

Comment: @Infinity yeah, actually you don't need that either. What you can do Dynamically create a Node inside the while loop of `while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)` and then assign the data part to this new Node.

Comment: I see the issue,  `while(headA){countA++; tempA = tempA->next;}
    while(headB){countB++; tempB = tempB->next;}`

The while is suppose to be while(tempA) and while(tempB). With the above code, it resulted in infinite loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106021/discussion-between-bandi-kishore-and-infinity).

Comment: okay, got it.. but still the output is coming different. it only prints the last element after the merging of the linked list

Comment: sir, thanks but now I have to go for the dinner. try to help

Comment: I guessed so. I'm updating my answer to accommodate this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to count elements, precreate result list and use so many loops, do everything in one loop:

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    Node *res = nullptr;
    Node **ptr = &res;
    while( headA || headB  ) {
        Node *curr = new Node;
        curr->next = nullptr;
        *ptr = curr;
        ptr = &curr->next;
        if( headB == nullptr || ( headA && headA->data < headB->data ) ) {
            curr->data = headA->data;
            headA = headA->next;
        } else {
            curr->data = headB->data;
            headB = headB->next;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note: you should not return raw pointer from a function - it can easily lead to a memory leak. You should use smart pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Node should contain something - you are creating a new node and assigning it to the end of the chain, but not saving a value in it at all, so the value is probably just defaulting to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
        res = res->next; <---

while(headA)
{
    res = headA;
}
while(headB)
{
    res = headB;
}
return res;
```

you returning res that is pointer to the end instead of the head.
Plus while(headB/headA) suppose to add reminder at the end of list but actually will loop infinite because no increment of the pointer.